# Como escrever um shorthand contendo vários argumentos de comprimento?

Tags: css

Considere o *shorthand* `background`.

Com ele, eu posso fazer isso:

```
.variable {
  background-image: url('image.png');
  background-size: 70px 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
}
```

Funciona perfeiramente.

Mas, ao usar o *shorthand* `background` com suas especificações (ex. `size`, `position` ...) com os valores de comprimento (ex. `px` e `%`) ele não funciona:

```
.variable {
background: url('image.png') 70px 60px no-repeat 95% 50%;
}
```

Como escrever, dentro de um *shorthand* (`background`), vários valores de comprimento (`70px` `60px` `90%` `50%`) de cada especificação (`size`, `position` ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que vc está procurando está descrito na documentação oficial, e vc pode livremente misturar valores em PX e %, desde que coloque uma `/` na sua declaração de *shorthand*.

Documentação: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#example-52742258

A grosso modo o que acontece é que quando vc declara ao mesmo tempo `bg-position` e `bg-size` no mesmo *shorthand* o browser não consegue identificar qual valor é para qual propriedade, então a convenção é que se deve usar um `/` na declaração e os valores após essa barra são considerados como o `bg-size`

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: url(https://placekitten.com/100/100) no-repeat 100% 100% / 200px 200px
  /* 100% é o bg-position
  200px é o bg-size */
}
```